# Galaxy S4 recognized but always "offline" in Flash Builder 4.7

Tags: android, flash-builder, galaxy

i try to make a flex application run from flash builder 4.7 on my galaxy s4. unfortunatley, it is always tagged as "offline" and "air not installed" in the device list. i tried out a lot of solutions, such as replacing the build tools in flash builder with the up-to-date android sdk files as suggested here: https://forums.adobe.com/message/5095835 but nothing works. the device is recognized but still appears to be offline without air installed.

- i have usb debugging enabled
- te air runtime is installed
- it worked in previous version and device connects without problems to unity3d
- i have the latest version of flashbuilder and the latest android version running.
- i work on MAC OS X 10.8.5

So, any solution or hint is appreciated! I need change an old app project, and right now i just can't do anything.

thank you

best regards

Wolfgang